# MySQL find common start of string/prefix of column in standard SELECT ... GROUP BY query

Tags: mysql, group-by

A fun little MySQL puzzle!

Given the dataset

| id | Description | Amount | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Food #1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Non-food #2 bla | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | Food banana | 5 | 1 |
| 4 | Non-food #2 foo | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | Non-food #2 foo bar | 3 | 2 |

How do I get this easily grouped by category into:

| Description | TotalAmount | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Food | 6 | 1 |
| Non-food #2 | 7 | 2 |

Thus a
`SELECT COMMON_PREFIX(Description) AS Description, SUM(Amount) AS TotalAmount, Category FROM table GROUP BY Category`

How to implement the fictious aggregate (GROUP BY) function `COMMON_PREFIX`?

I tried GROUP_CONCATenating the Description separated by a unique separator and with REGEXP find the common prefix, this would work were it not that MySQL doesn't support back references in the search string (it works in other languages that do support them).

Any other ideas?

To be clear, I need the first words (no matter how many) that all GROUPED BY records have in common. The dataset is small, so GROUP_CONCAT, if needed, is an option.

**Now of course, good database design would prevent a query like this from happening.** But sometimes you have to add something in an existing application and it isn't worth redesigning your database for just that one little query that is sparsely used. Adding fields to tables that are nearly never used clutters your database and make matters more confusing as well...

Comment: I think you mean _prefix,_ not suffix, based on your example output.

Comment: THANKS of course! My latin classes at school were 40 years ago... Bit rusty hahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give you quick solution. It's not the best because it assumes you know how many words can be at most in the common prefix. In this example I used 6 words MAX, you can easily increase it as you need.

Please let me know if that's not your case and you need really generic solution for ANY number of words - I can do it as well, but it will be harder.

The idea is the following: for each group (grouped by category) I get MIN(description) and MAX(description). If they're equal - great, we know it's the same within the category, if they're different, then try split them by words and check if first 5 words are the same, if not - then if first 4 words are the same etc.

Here is the working SQL Query:

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN d_min = d_max THEN d_min
    WHEN d_min5 = d_max5 THEN d_min5
    WHEN d_min4 = d_max4 THEN d_min4
    WHEN d_min3 = d_max3 THEN d_min3
    WHEN d_min2 = d_max2 THEN d_min2
    WHEN d_min1 = d_max1 THEN d_min1  
    ELSE ''
  END description,
  category,
  total_amount
FROM (
  SELECT
    d_min,
    d_max,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(d_min, ' ', 1) d_min1,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(d_max, ' ', 1) d_max1,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(d_min, ' ', 2) d_min2,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(d_max, ' ', 2) d_max2,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(d_min, ' ', 3) d_min3,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(d_max, ' ', 3) d_max3,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(d_min, ' ', 4) d_min4,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(d_max, ' ', 4) d_max4,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(d_min, ' ', 5) d_min5,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(d_max, ' ', 5) d_max5,
    category,
    total_amount
  FROM (
    SELECT
      MIN(description) d_min,
      MAX(description) d_max,
      category,
      SUM(amount) total_amount
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY category
  ) t1
) t2
```

[image: SQL Query Result]

Comment: Hi Maxim... Max 6 words is fine! I think the clever thing you did with MIN and MAX is that you cannot have any other values between them with a different prefix. Very clever indeed, I would not have thought of that! I did think of brute forcing comparing different numbers of words, but I got stuck because I could not figure out how to do this over all records. You showed we don't need to. So simple and yet I wouldn't have thought of it. Thank you!

Comment: A fiddle is here: https://dbfiddle.uk/qnq5o8kp

Answer (score 1):

### Not a solution.

The below query provides all possible prefixes which are found in more than one row.

```
CREATE TABLE tab (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `Description` VARCHAR(100),
  `Amount` INTEGER,
  `Category` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO tab
  (`id`, `Description`, `Amount`, `Category`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'Food #1', '1', '1'),
  ('2', 'Non-food bla', '3', '2'),
  ('3', 'Food banana', '5', '1'),
  ('4', 'Non-food foo', '1', '2'),
  ('5', 'Multiword prefix #1', '3', '2'),
  ('6', 'Multiword prefix #2', '1', '1'),
  ('7', 'Lonely prefix', '1', '1'),
  ('8', 'Multiword', '1', '1');

SELECT * FROM tab;
```

> ```
> Records: 8  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

| id | Description | Amount | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Food #1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Non-food bla | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | Food banana | 5 | 1 |
| 4 | Non-food foo | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | Multiword prefix #1 | 3 | 2 |
| 6 | Multiword prefix #2 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | Lonely prefix | 1 | 1 |
| 8 | Multiword | 1 | 1 |

```
WITH RECURSIVE 
cte AS (
  SELECT id, description, 1 amount, SUBSTRING_INDEX(description, ' ', 1) prefix
  FROM tab
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t1.id, t1.description, 
         t1.amount + 1, SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.description, ' ', t1.amount + 1)
  FROM cte t1
  JOIN tab t2 ON t1.id <> t2.id
             AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.description, ' ', t1.amount + 1) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(t2.description, ' ', t1.amount + 1)
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
       tab.id, tab.description, cte.prefix
FROM tab
JOIN cte ON LOCATE(cte.prefix, tab.description) = 1
ORDER BY id, LENGTH(prefix)
```

| id | description | prefix |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Food #1 | Food |
| 2 | Non-food bla | Non-food |
| 3 | Food banana | Food |
| 4 | Non-food foo | Non-food |
| 5 | Multiword prefix #1 | Multiword |
| 5 | Multiword prefix #1 | Multiword prefix |
| 6 | Multiword prefix #2 | Multiword |
| 6 | Multiword prefix #2 | Multiword prefix |
| 7 | Lonely prefix | Lonely |
| 8 | Multiword | Multiword |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sQ9VZkmJ)

But the fiddle demonstrates the problem. Source row 8 is a member of a group with common prefix "Multiword" which contains 3 rows totally. 2 another rows have longer common prefix "Multiword prefix". But if we use this longer prefix for these 2 rows then the row 8 will stay alone in its shorter prefix group... correct solution needs the longer prefix to be ignored, and a group which uses more short prefix group of 3 members to be returned. But this solution may be too complex.. and I don't know does this is reasonable.

And another problem. Source row 7 have uniquely prefixed description. My query returns only 1st word of it.

Comment: Thank you. Same categories have same prefixes (however the number of words that are the same is unknown), so no need for having different prefixes whilst categorie is the same.